# How to create 2 machines and place code on Amazon Web Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

We were running an image website on AWS micro instance. The website has a static part and has an image processing part. User upload upto 500 images and we process it. AWS micro instance is not able to process these images. So now we want to buy a bigger instance and push codes of this processing on that machine while retaining the static pages on the free Micro instance. Help me know how to create machines and split codes between them and make them interact as a seamless process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3 for storing image and not purchase new EC2 instance, you can store image on S3 thane ec2 can connect and get images form storage, its faster and easier

Comment: No No.. We need a high processing instance as that part of website takes user images.. process it(themes, colors, size etc) and send it back to them for download. So its pretty much real time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do, but perhaps if you want to everything with Micro Instance you would be penalized if cross the shared threshold as your compute power is shared.

There are ways you can ensure you don't cross the threshold but still get your work done on Micro Instance.

1. Use your upload module to store the images in S3 and push those to **`Amazon Elastic Transcoder`** for the image processing job and once it is done give it back the processed image URL.
2. Use your upload module to store the images in the S3 and get URL [ Keys / references ] in a SQS Queue and process the image by your own server in the EC2 and put back the processed images in S3 and provide the URL of the finished images. This wasy you pick the image one by one always and the load of your micro instance is balanced.

PS : You can always couple your system with SNS, SQS to make it stateless and efficient. Making everything in realtime would be doable in the initial stages but as your system scales; you need to decouple things. Using either of the above strategies would help you get to that journey.